# how to get load time of a web element by selenium webdriver using java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, load-time

Below is sample code:

```
StopWatch iFrameload=  new StopWatch();
iFrameload.start();
List<WebElement> ele= webdriver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println("Total frames: "+ ele.size());           
iFrameload.stop();  
long iFrame_loadTime_ms= iFrameload.getTime();
long iFrame_loadTime_Seconds=iFrame_loadTime_ms/1000;
System.out.println("iFrame load time: " +iFrame_loadTime_ms+" "+ "milliseconds");
System.out.println("iFrame load time: " +iFrame_loadTime_Seconds+" "+ "seconds");
```

Comment: is your iframe taking long time to load?  as per your code, ti will give you the time taken for finding the all iframe elements not the time take to load the elements.

Comment: Did you try out the webdriver listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

driver.get("Some url");

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("ID of some element on the page which will load"));
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = finish - start; 
System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);
```